# How to add code area css style to HTML

Tags: css

I am trying to create a blog in wordpress. Since I might need to add some code blocks to my posts, I was wondering if there is any CSS style to represent code block.

A very simple example would be stackoverflow code tag (shown below)

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   alert('this is example of what i need to do ') ; 
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: It's called syntax highlighting

Comment: how can we render this to our html code

Comment: Check out Google Prettyprint: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using wordpress, there are plugins to do that. Just by looking at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/syntax-highlighting there seems to be quite a few to choose from.